# selecionar todos os registros da tabela armazenada numa session

Tags: php

quero armazenar todos os registros das minhas tabelas dentro de uma `session`, quando eu chamo meus registros ele só puxa 1 resultado

```
class CRUD extends Config {

    private $query;

    private function prepExec($prep, $exec) {

        $this->query = $this->getConn()->prepare($prep);
        $this->query->execute($exec);

    }

    public function select($fields, $table, $prep, $exec) {

        $this->prepExec("SELECT ".$fields." FROM ".$table." ".$prep."", $exec);
        return $this->query;

    }

}
```

tentei assim

**index.php**

```
session_start();
$not = $crd->select('*', 'noticias', 'ORDER BY id DESC', array());
foreach ($not as $reg) :
    $_SESSION['slug_noticia'] = $not['slug_noticia'];
    $_SESSION['nome_noticia'] = $not['nome_noticia'];
endforeach;
```

e assim

```
$not = $crd->select('*', 'noticias', 'ORDER BY id DESC', array());
foreach ($not as $reg) :
    $_SESSION['reg'] = $reg;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer criar um array de registros dentro da sessão, precisaria fazer assim:

```
session_start();
$not = $crd->select('*', 'noticias', 'ORDER BY id DESC', array());
foreach ($not as $key => $reg) :
    $_SESSION['slug_noticia'][$key] = $not['slug_noticia'];
    $_SESSION['nome_noticia'][$key] = $not['nome_noticia'];
endforeach
```

Da maneira que você faz atualmente, você atribui um valor numa iteração do loop, porém na próxima iteração você a sobrescreve, já que não definiu nenhum índice na sua atribuição para criar a "listagem".

Além disso, dá pra simplificar esse trecho do foreach pra gerar uma centralização dos dados num índice da sessão só:

Exemplo:

```
session_start();

$not = $crd->select('*', 'noticias', 'ORDER BY id DESC', array());
foreach ($not as $reg) {
    $_SESSION['noticias'][] = $not;
}
```

O operador `[]` tem como finalidade adicionar novos itens "ao final" do array à medida que é chamada.

Como dica, Nesse último exemplo, você poderia melhorar ainda mais sua atribuição usando o id da notícia como índice:

```
 $_SESSION['noticias'][$not['id']] = $not;
```

Para recuperar os valores da sessão posteriormente, você pode fazer um `foreach`:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['noticias'])) {

    foreach ($_SESSION['noticias'] as $id => $noticia) {
          echo $noticia['titulo'];
    }
}
```

Comment: man porque? `Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array` nessa linha `$_SESSION['noticias'][$not['id']] = $not;`

Comment: @Mayron debugar é vida... Se está retornando isso, é porque você não rodou o `fetch` do `PDOStatment` em algum lugar.